# iOS7 Safari with Switch Control access

Tags: html, ios7, safari, accessibility, switchcontrol

I'm trying to make book reading on tarheelreader.org easier on the iPad using the new iOS7 "Switch Control" accessibility feature. I've got a bluetooth switch configured to do "Move to Next Item" and "Select Item". With these two switches I can move around the page and access the site but too many clicks are required to simply go to the next page.

I'd like the Next Page link to be the first item highlighted on the page.

My experiments indicate that they select the items in DOM order and they appear to ignore tabindex.

I guess I could add a javascript hack to move the Next Page link to the top of the DOM but I'm hoping there is something cleaner than that. Perhaps some ARIA attributes?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a hack that works to let me choose the first link to be highlighted. It's ugly but so is the rest of the ios.js file I added to contain my ios specific hacks.

I added

```
// hack for switch control on iOS7. I'm moving the next page link to first
// in the DOM so it will be highlighted as the first choice
$('.active-page').prepend($('.active-page .thr-next-link'));
```

which simply moves the Next Page link up to the top of the DOM of the active page.

It seems in my simple tests to work. I'd love something more elegant and general with WAI-ARIA properties.